# Traverse dictionary keys by summing up values

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to traverse through dictionary by summing up the values of the keys until it reaches 50 and then write those keys to files.

For example:

```
fruits={'mangoes':10,'banana':20,'orange':20,'grapes':40,'apple':10,'strawberry':20,'cherry':30}
```

The output should be multiple bags with batch of "maximum 50" fruits.

In this example:

```
bag1: 
mangoes,
banana,
orange

bag2:
grapes,
apple

bag3:
strawberry,
cherry
```

Comment: Are there any constraints about wasted space in the bags? I can see that the bags you've listed all add up to 50 exactly, but would (mangoes, banana, apple), (grapes), (orange, strawberry), (cherry) also be a valid solution? Because that's a much easier problem than if it needs to be the optimal set of bags.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @babbageclunk  The dictionary needs to be traversed in the same order until it reaches "maximum 50".  For e.g: if oranges are only 10, then the next item is grapes=40, by which sum becomes 80 , so the bag1 only contains mangoes,banana,orange even the sum is less than 50.

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, that was what I was getting at.

Comment: It seems a bit weird to be relying on the order of the dictionary, but that might just be me not used to dicts maintaining insertion order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it to be in dictionary order I'd do something like this:

```
def bags(fruits, max_size):
    bag = []
    current_size = 0
    for name, count in fruits.items():
        if count + current_size > max_size:
            yield bag
            bag = []
            current_size = 0
        bag.append(name)
        current_size += count
    if bag:
        yield bag

for bag in bags(fruits, 50):
    print bag
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just wrote something that will recursively track the elements and current sums. I think it will give every option with every sub-option. It then just builds the bags from the generator items. (Python 3, for `yeild from`)

```html
def subset_sum(fruits, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
    if partial_sum == target:
        yield partial
    if partial_sum >= target:
        return
    for i, n in enumerate(fruits):
        remaining = fruits[i + 1:]
        yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fruits={'mangoes':10,'banana':20,'orange':10,'grapes':40,'apple':10,'strawberry':20,'cherry':30}
    fruits=tuple((k,v) for k,v in fruits.items())
    result = subset_sum(fruits,50)
    for i, n in enumerate(result):
        print('Bag {}: {}'.format(i, ' '.join([f[0] for f in n])))
```

```html
Bag 0: mangoes banana orange apple
Bag 1: mangoes banana strawberry
Bag 2: mangoes orange apple strawberry
Bag 3: mangoes orange cherry
Bag 4: mangoes grapes
Bag 5: mangoes apple cherry
Bag 6: banana orange strawberry
Bag 7: banana apple strawberry
Bag 8: banana cherry
Bag 9: orange grapes
Bag 10: orange apple cherry
Bag 11: grapes apple
Bag 12: strawberry cherry
```

Comment: The above given solution calculates all combination of given "target sum" which does not solve the problem. I want to have items traversed in the same order until it reaches "maximum 50" and then collect the next items in next bag.